# Is there a time limit for downloading/installing a large app?

Tags: downloading, android-tv, nvidia-shield

I have a Shield Android TV (first version with 5.2 installed).  I'm trying to install Half Life 2: episode one from the play store.  But it's not working properly.

The app is 2.6GB and over DSL it's going to take a while.  I'm not getting any errors, but after a while (something more than 50 minutes) when I check I find the install has stopped and I'm back at an "install" prompt with no indication of any saved progress.  Selecting install just starts the process from the beginning again.

As this is a paid app, I doubt I have the option to just download an APK via a different tool and sideload.

Is this a timeout on the system?  Any workarounds likely (short of a faster network)?

ADDED.
On earlier attempts, when I cleared the screensaver, there was no message.  On my most recent try, I kept the screensaver off and around (exactly?) an hour into the download an error appeared.

> Error
>
> "Half-Life 2: Episode One" can't be downloaded. Try again, and if the problem continues, get help troubleshooting. (Error code: 495)

The phrase "get help troubleshooting" in the message appears to be a link, but the virtual cursor doesn't appear here, so I can't click or inspect it, only dismiss the entire dialog.